# three.js from npm: import THREE.Lut()

Tags: javascript, three.js, es6-modules

I've install the three package from npm, and tried to call

```
lut = new THREE.Lut( colorMap, numberOfColors );
```

I'm getting `"export 'Lut' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'`.

The `Lut.js` file can be found in `\node_modules\three\examples\js\math`, but it doesn't contain `export` statements and needs `three.js` itself.

I've tried `import 'three/examples/js/math/Lut';` and other conventions, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import Lut from 'three/examples/js/math/Lut'
```

Then

```
let lut = new Lut(...);
```

Presumably you can also do this instead

```
import THREE from 'three'
let lut = new THREE.Lut(...);
```

**Edit**

It doesn't look like `three.js` allow you to import the examples at this time there are plenty of suggestions/workarounds that you can look at in this issue, but it doesn't look like it is going to be implemented any time soon:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562

Comment: `import THREE from 'three'` is not working, and the first suggestion fails as well. It looks like `Lut.js` has a call to `THREE` object from inside.

Comment: @galah92 It doesn't look like three.js allow you to import the examples at this time there are plenty of suggestions/workarounds that you can look at in this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562, but it doesn't look like it is going to be implemented any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays(*), useful examples are also available *as modules* under `three/examples/jsm`:

```
import { Lut } from "three/examples/jsm/math/Lut";
//        Notice that little 'm' here ⬆
```

(*) Since [r109](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/7b53b66a5d21989a599748279763548ef9ab3d82) I think.